# Does $f\in\mathcal{O}(g)$ mean that $f$ is of smaller order than $g$?

Tags: analysis

I want to show that $f$ is of smaller order than $g$. My idea is to show that $f\in\mathcal{O}(g)$, but:

Does $f\in\mathcal{O}(g)$ mean that $f$ is of  smaller order than $g$?

Comment: No because also $g\in\mathcal O(g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f \in \mathcal O(g)$ means that $f$ is of *smaller or equal* asymptotic order than $g$.

If you want to state that $f$ is of strictly smaller order than $g$, use the little-oh instead: $f\in o(g)$.

---

Note also that both of these notations depend on a choice of a particular limiting process for the independent variable. Landau notation is commonly used for speaking about the asymptotic behavior either for $x\to 0$ or $x\to+\infty$, which leads to very different relations between concrete functions.

For example, $x^2$ is $o(x^3)$ for $x\to+\infty$, but it is the other way around for $x\to 0$.

Comment: Please let me give the following example. Assume that $\text{Prob}(A_n)\leq\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ for almost all $n$ for some constant $c>0$. Then $(\text{Prob}(A_n))^2\leq\frac{c^2}{n}$ for almost all $n$. Moreover, then $(\text{Prob}(A_n))^2\in o(n^{-1/2})$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(\text{Prob}(A_n))^2}{n^{-1/2}}\leqslant\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{n}}=0$, Right? So this means, that $(\text{Prob}(A_n))^2$ is of smaller order than $n^{-1/2}$, right?

Comment: @mathfemi: Yes.